# Vite React and Express Server deployment on render

Tags: reactjs, express, render, vite

I have created a react application using Vite and the backend with Express.js. Everything works fine in development mode, but when I deployed them on Render, the front end isn't connecting to the server anymore, and I can't find much help on google or even the official doc (https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html)

This is what I have in vite.config.js

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://face-detect-server.onrender.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And this is one of the hook I use to make request in React

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const useAuth = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async (method, url, data) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      if (method === "post" && url === "/api/users") {
        const { username, email, password } = data;

        ...
      }

      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError(error.response.data.message);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { fetchData, isLoading, error };
};

export default useAuth;
```

Everything works in Vite and Preview (both connected to hosted server), just when I deploy React on render, then hosted front end stops connecting to the server.

This is what I have set up on Render, my guess is something to do with the dist directory

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.